# MySQL - randomizing where condition doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlperformance

I created a MySQL table in memory (using ENGINE = MEMORY) with **5 million records**. 
The table has 50+ columns and is **indexed using only 1 column (INSTRUMENT_ID)**.

I wanted to check the performance of the database using this table. And for this I thought of using the following SQL to be executed repeatedly in which the WHERE clause is randomized using as simple logic.

```
SELECT * 
from ATSDN_TRA_TRADE_PRINT 
where INSTRUMENT_ID = (SELECT CONCAT('PERFINS',(SELECT LPAD((ROUND(RAND()*10000)),5,'0'))))
order by TRADE_DATE
LIMIT 1000;
```

INSTRUMENT_IDs are as follows

```
PERFINS000001
PERFINS000002
PERFINS000003
..
..
..
PERFINS009997
PERFINS009998
PERFINS009999
```

The above returns records, BUT the problem is **each record shows different INSTRUMENT_ID values** instead of same INSTRUMENT_ID.

Also I noted that the **above SQL takes more time to execute** than when I use a straight forward SQL like the one given below

```
SELECT * 
from ATSDN_TRA_TRADE_PRINT 
where INSTRUMENT_ID = (SELECT'PERFINS03943')
order by TRADE_DATE
LIMIT 1000;
```

Can someone please help me to figure out why ... My knowledge in MYSQL is very limited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the same instrument id for the test for each row, then you need to call `rand()` only once.  You can do this using a variable:

```
SELECT attp.*
from ATSDN_TRA_TRADE_PRINT attp CROSS JOIN
     (select @id := CONCAT('PERFINS', LPAD((ROUND(RAND()*10000)), 5, '0')) ) vars
where attp.INSTRUMENT_ID = @id
order by attp.TRADE_DATE
LIMIT 1000;
```

By the way, you are using `select` in places where there is no need.  You can just call functions and use values without an extra layer of subqueries.

Comment: Thanks Gordon ... That was very helpful.
1 more thing ... The query as you suggested takes around 2 seconds to execute ... where as the last query posted in my question (without randomizing) executes in 1.3 seconds. I think the delay is due to the joining ?

Comment: @afwsl2003 . . . No.  The `cross join` would have basically no affect on the query.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `RAND()` in your `WHERE` clause, it's executed for every row in your table. This is very slow. Instead you probably want something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ATSDN_TRA_TRADE_PRINT
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @my_rand := ROUND(RAND()*10000)) var_init
WHERE INSTRUMENT_ID = CONCAT('PERFINS', LPAD(@my_rand, 5, '0'))
ORDER BY TRADE_DATE
LIMIT 1000;
```